# TX TextControl How to traverse through each Cell in a Table

Tags: vb6, txtextcontrol

I have a word document which contains some text and a table.

I am loading this document in TX TextControl.

I want to traverse through each cell in TX TextControl and extract the contents of each cell and save them in various fields in RTF format in a DB.

How can I traverse through each cell in a Table easily?

I have developed a solution but this code at times is extracting the cell borders also and this is messing up everything.

Here is the code snippet:

```
txImportFile.SelStart = txImportFile.TableCellStart(CurTableID, RowNum, 2) - 1
txImportFile.SelLength = txImportFile.TableCellLength(CurTableID, RowNum, 2)
mtd_question.RTFSelText = txImportFile.RTFSelText
'Code to save textracted text and graphics to DB goes here
```

I want to note that the table is very big and spans across many pages. A documents average size is 47 pages from which the table itself occupies around 31 pages.

TIA

Yogi Yang

Comment: TX Textcontrol: is that some sort of RTF control?  If so, why aren't you using the native RTF control that comes with VB6?

Comment: Yes it is a RTF control with features similar to MS Word! Native RTF control cannot handle many advance features in documents like Tables, Sections, multi columns, etc.

Comment: The native control can be "tricked" into handling the more advanced features.  See my answer [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1588186).

Comment: Note also that that answer is two years old.  Currently, there is a version 2 of TOM, which is included in RichEdit version 6 and above.  You should be able to substitute the TOM 2 objects in the code.  For example, where it says ITextDocument put ITextDocument2.  (All of this stuff is well documented on MSDN and the blogs.  The VB6 implementation is a little more obscure.)